# Get Data from HttpGet Action Method and pass them to HttpPost Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am just asking myself wether it is possible to get values from an HttpGet Actionmethod and pass them to the HttpPost Actionmethod.

Here is the Code:

#### ContactAdminController

```
public class ContactAdminController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult SendMail()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendMail(ContactAdminViewModel contactAdmin)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (DQL.CheckUsernameAndEmail(contactAdmin.username, contactAdmin.email))
                {
                    Mail.SendMail.SendForgotPassword(contactAdmin.username, contactAdmin.email, contactAdmin.message);
                    return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your username is not associated with the email adress");
                return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("LogIn", "Account");
        }

    }
```

#### SendMail.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.ContactAdminViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>SendMail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.username, "username")
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.username)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.email, "email")
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.email)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.message, "Your message")
            <p>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.message, new { cols = "35", rows = "10", @style = "resize:none" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.message)
            </p>
        </p>

        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Send", "SendMail", "ContactAdmin")
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### ContactAdminViewModel

```
public class ContactAdminViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to fill in a username")]
        public string username { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to fill in an email adress")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to fill a message for the admin")]
        public string message { get; set; }
    }
```

My problem is that I don't really know how to pass the values from the EditorFors and TextAreaFor to the HttpPost SendMail method. I didn't find anything appropriate on stackoverflow nor did I found any Solution from the asp.net Homepage. I hope someone could help me :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use [Html.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a form to submit to the controller, are you? You can do this in Razor by using [`BeginForm FormExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "ContactAdmin", FormMethod.Post))
{
   //Your form here with submit button
}
```

- This method writes an opening `<form>` tag to the response. When the user submits the form, the request will be processed by an action method.
- You can use this method in a `using` block. In that case, the method renders the closing `</form>` tag at the end of the using block.
- This method has many overloads but this allows to define `FormMethod`:The `HTTP` method for processing the form, either `GET` or `POST`.

So, as you want to `POST` to the controller,  `SendMail.cshtml` will become

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "ContactAdmin", FormMethod.Post))
    {
<div>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.username, "username")
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.username)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.email, "email")
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.email)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.message, "Your message")
            <p>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.message, new { cols = "35", rows = "10", @style = "resize:none" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.message)
            </p>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" />
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You also need a submit input.

Comment: @Romoku That is what my comment interprets, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah but `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` would be more complete.

Comment: Thank you so much @BhushanFirake!! This works fine! But now I have another Problem. When I leave all the EditorsFor and the TextAreaFor blank I still can submit. How I can add some validation to this for fitting the ViewModel?

Comment: @Superbyte You will need to add some client-side validation using jquery or javascript and then you can also use your `ErrorMessages` in your viewModel by using some js files. Google it...

Comment: @BhushanFirake Thank you! Now the client side validation works. Now the next question :) When the user types in his / her username and password it is checked if the combination is saved in the database. If so the mail is sent. But when the username is not associated with the email adress I'd like to show an error message. Can you give me some tips how to solve this?

Comment: @Superbyte Search for AJAX...you can find similar questions and answers on stackoverflow..

Comment: @BhushanFirake I googled now for a while but I don't find anything appropriate. Do you have a link or something like that for me?